# Select count of rows in another table in a Postgres SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't know quite how to phrase this so please help me with the title as well. :)

I have two tables. Let's call them `A` and `B`. The `B` table has a `a_id` foreign key that points at `A.id`. Now I would like to write a `SELECT` statement that fetches all `A` records, with an additional column containing the count of `B` records per `A` row for each row in the result set.

I'm using Postgresql 9 right now, but I guess this would be a generic SQL question?

EDIT:

In the end I went for trigger-cache solution, where `A.b_count` is updated via a function each time `B` changes.

Comment: It might be better to use a JOIN for performance reasons.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.a_id = A.id) AS TOT FROM A
```

Comment: Does this type of nested select have a performance penalty worth worrying about?

Comment: Yes, there is. The nested select will be executed for each row that is retrieved from table A.

Comment: Hm, so I'm guessing that it'd be much more efficient to create a column in A table, and update the value with a trigger when B table is modified?

Comment: Keeping a cached column would be the most efficient for reading but introduces it's problems during updates.  The most efficient way of doing this without a cache column is to use a JOIN and GROUP BY (see my answer as an example.)

Comment: This solution is inefficient (slow).

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, if there's a `WHERE` clause (e.g. `WHERE A.name = 'example'`) at the back of this query that only matches one row (or a very small number of rows) from table `A`, this method would not be any slower than the other methods because table `B` is only queried once.  It might even be faster than the other solutions if column `B.a_id` is indexed.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 40):

I think the comment by @intgr in another answer is so valuable I'm putting forward this as an alternate answer as this method allows you to filter the calculated column efficiently.

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  COUNT(b.id) AS b_count

FROM a
INNER JOIN b on b.a_id = a.id
WHERE a.id > 50 AND b.ID < 100 -- example of filtering joined tables, optional

GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(b.id) > 10 -- example of filtering calculated column, optional
ORDER BY a.id
```

Comment: For people looking to filter with count 0 as in `HAVING COUNT(b.id) = 0`, use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and it will work.

Answer (score 15):

The subquery solution given above is inefficient. The trigger solution is probably best in a mostly-read database, but for the record here's a join approach that will perform better than a subquery:

```
SELECT a.id, a.xxx, count(*)
FROM a JOIN b ON (b.a_id = a.id)
GROUP BY a.id, a.xxx
```

If you're using Django ORM you can simply write:

```
res = A.objects.annotate(Count('b'))
print res[0].b__count  # holds the result count
```

Comment: Hm, there seems to be many ways to do this. :) I've implmented the triggers, and since this is mostly-read part of the application (it's a listing of directory-type items with item count per directory record on the dashboard), I think it's the safest bet.

Comment: what if you have dozens of column in a?

Comment: Since PostgreSQL 9.1 it's enough to do "GROUP BY primary_key_column", in earlier versions you'd have to name all chosen columns in the GROUP BY.

Comment: In case of 1 to 0...m relation, the count(*) will return 1 even if there are zero FK rows. Count(b.id) would be correct.

Answer (score 12):

Accepted answer is inefficient (slow) based on my tests. The subquery of table B executing for every row of table A. I'm using following approach based on grouping and joining. It works much faster:

```
SELECT A.id, QTY.quantity FROM A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(B.a_id) AS quantity, B.a_id FROM B GROUP BY B.a_id) AS QTY
ON A.id = QTY.a_id
```

Another variant:

```
SELECT A.id, COUNT(B.a_id) AS quantity FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
GROUP BY A.id
```

Comment: Note: Only the first variant allows to select different counts from multiple tables. The second variant will return a product of all the counts if more than one `LEFT JOIN` / `COUNT` is added.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question:

```
SELECT a.id, a.other_column, ..., 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b where b.a_id = a.id) AS b_count
FROM a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst a sub-query may be less efficient, how much less efficient depends on the use-case.  Another thing to consider is the filters that are being used.

I have a Table A of "Approvers"
I have a Table B of "Approval tasks"

I want to show a list of ALL approvers along with a count of how many ACTIVE approval tasks they have.  Now, my knowledge of SQL is limited, but no matter what I tried with the different types of join, my list of approvers was incomplete.  Why?  I need to have a filter on table B so that only active tasks are returned.  If an approver only has inactive/complete tasks, there is no count.  This should show 0, but for some reason it just doesn't show the row at all.

So, I use a sub-query and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hello Gryzor. Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please clarify your answer with a code example explaining what you wrote? Also, please confirm that your answer is substantively different than the five answers already posted.

Comment: It doesn't need a code example as plenty have been provided and mine is no different.  I'm just saying that the correct solution depends.  All of the above join examples provided don't work if a row in table A doesn't have any corresponding rows in table B.  Table A can have 10 reviewers, but if one of those reviewers has no "active tasks" in table B, the query will only return 9 rows.  This might be fine for some purposes, but for my own where I still need to return all 10 approvers regardless, joins don't work.  Hence why sometimes a sub-query is fine, even if not the most optimal.