# Select where count of another table is zero

Tags: sql

I have two tables (`questions` and `answers`), and wish to select the rows from `questions` only when the corresponding count in `answers` is zero, in other words, when there are no answers which match `questionid`.

My query so far is:

```
SELECT q.* , COUNT(a.id) FROM questions q LEFT OUTER JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.questionid WHERE COUNT(a.id)=0
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to do it like that, but it's not working. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try,

```
SELECT q.*
FROM questions q LEFT OUTER JOIN answers a 
           ON q.id = a.questionid 
WHERE a.questionid IS NULL
```

Comment: All [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26727307/8244632) answer needed was `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can to use `not exsist` as below:

```
SELECT q.*  
FROM questions q 
where not exists ( select 1 from answers  a
                   where q.id = a.questionid
                 )
```