# Select count of rows in two other tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables. The main one in which I want to retrieve some information and two others for row count only.

I used a request like this :

```
SELECT A.*,
    COUNT(B.id) AS b_count
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B on B.a_id = A.id
WHERE A.id > 50 AND B.ID < 100
GROUP BY A.id
```

from Gerry Shaw's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535782/select-count-of-rows-in-another-table-in-a-postgres-select-statement). It works perfectly but only for one table.

Now I need to add the row count for the third (C) table. I tried

```
SELECT A.*,
    COUNT(B.id) AS b_count
    COUNT(C.id) AS c_count
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B on B.a_id = A.id
    LEFT JOIN C on C.a_id = A.id
GROUP BY A.id
```

but, because of the two left joins, my `b_count` and my `c_count` are false and equal to each other. In fact my actual `b_count` and `c_count` are equal to `real_b_count*real_c_count`. Any idea of how I could fix this without adding a lot of complexity/subqueries ?

---

Data sample as requested:

```
Table A (primary key : id)
id    | data1 | data2
------+-------+-------
1     |  0,45 |  0,79
----------------------
2     | -2,24 | -0,25
----------------------
3     |  1,69 |  1,23

Table B (primary key : (a_id,fruit))
a_id  | fruit
------+-------
1     | apple
------+-------
1     | banana
--------------
2     | apple

Table C (primary key : (a_id,color))
a_id  | color
------+-------
2     | blue
------+-------
2     | purple
--------------
3     | blue
```

---

expected result:

```
id    | data1 | data2 | b_count | c_count
------+-------+-------+---------+--------
1     |  0,45 |  0,79 | 2       | 0
----------------------+---------+--------
2     | -2,24 | -0,25 | 1       | 2
----------------------+---------+--------
3     |  1,69 |  1,23 | 0       | 1
```

Comment: Post some sample data and your expected result will help better.

Comment: data  sample added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions. One is using subqueries behind `SELECT`

```
SELECT A.*,
    (
       SELECT COUNT(B.id) FROM B WHERE B.a_id = A.id AND B.ID < 100
    ) AS b_count,
    (
       SELECT COUNT(C.id) FROM C WHERE C.a_id = A.id
    ) AS c_count
FROM A
WHERE A.id > 50
```

the second are two SQL queries joined together

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.c_count
FROM
(
    SELECT A.*,
        COUNT(B.id) AS b_count
    FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B on B.a_id = A.id
    WHERE A.id > 50 AND B.ID < 100
    GROUP BY A.id
) t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT A.*,
        COUNT(C.id) AS c_count
    FROM A
        LEFT JOIN C on C.a_id = A.id
    WHERE A.id > 50
    GROUP BY A.id
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

I prefer the second syntax since it clearly shows the optimizer that you are interested in `GROUP BY`, however, the query plans are usually the same.

Comment: Radim Bača Rogério Carvalho Batista @Blank  Jaydip Jadhav Matthew Baker Thanks a lot for your help. I upvoted all of you because it helped me a lot. I decided to accept Radim Bača 's answer as it was the first, very performance-friendly and the most detailed. I took the second query because the first one duplicate columns of table A and the second one is easier to maintain (I can select more or less columns by adding them in a single place). Maybe you could edit your answer to put the second one in head. Thanks again !

Comment: @txemsukr you are welcome. I have updated the `GROUP BY` query in order to avoid duplicate columns.

Answer (score 1):

If tables B & C also have their own key fields, then you can use COUNT DISTINCT on the primary key rather than foreign key.  That gets around the multi-line problem you see on link to several tables.  If you can post the table structures then we can advise further.

Comment: data structure added

Answer (score 1):

That is the easier way I can think:

```
Create table #a (id int, data1 float, data2 float)
Create table #b (id int, fruit varchar(50))
Create table #c (id int, color varchar(50))

Insert into #a
SELECT 1, 0.45, 0.79
UNION ALL SELECT 2, -2.24, -0.25
UNION ALL SELECT 3,  1.69, 1.23

Insert into #b
SELECT 1, 'apple'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'banana'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'orange'


Insert into #c
SELECT 2, 'blue'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'purple'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'orange'



SELECT #a.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(#b.id) FROM #b where #b.id = #a.id) AS b_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(#c.id) FROM #c where #c.id = #a.id) AS b_count
FROM #a
ORDER BY #a.id
```

Result:

```
id  data1   data2   b_count b_count
1   0,45    0,79    2   0
2   -2,24   -0,25   1   2
3   1,69    1,23    0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT A.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(B.id) FROM B WHERE B.a_id = A.id) AS b_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(C.id) FROM C WHERE C.a_id = A.id) AS c_count
FROM A
```

Answer (score 1):

If table b and c have unique id, you can try this:

```
SELECT A.*,
    COUNT(distinct B.fruit) AS b_count,
    COUNT(distinct C.color) AS c_count
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B on B.a_id = A.id
    LEFT JOIN C on C.a_id = A.id
GROUP BY A.id
```

See [**SQLFiddle MySQL demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f41a18/2).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately table B and C don't have a unique id, information added in first post

Comment: @txemsukr Then try to use `fruit` and `color`, and check demo in SQLFiddle.

Comment: The couple (id,fruit) is unique and is the primary key. Same for (id, color).

Comment: @txemsukr Then you can replace `B.fruit` to  `CONCAT(B.id, B.fruit)` and same for table c.